# Network Unreachable Firefox

Tags: networking, firefox, network-manager, internet

I just downloaded Ubuntu today, but I can't visit any website and if I ping google.com or 8.8.4.4 then there is the error Network is unreachable.

I tried to edit resolv.conf and added nameserver 8.8.8.8 and nameserver 8.8.4.4 but still nothing.

Comment: "Network is unreachable" means that your network you are connected to is either not permitting you access, or you are firewalled off from certain protocols/behavior, or your networking is misconfigured on your machine.